# How to get the background colour of a loaded swf?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash, loader

When you load in an external swf at runtime is there any way to get the background colour of the swf? - That is the stage background colour.
The loaded swf is uploaded by users, who may or may not know the correct colour.
I know that normally this is specified in the HTML code to embed a swf, but if you run a swf in the standalone player it will display the correct colour, so the information should be there somewhere.
What I want to do is to create a background behind the loaded swf, so it will display like intended.

EDIT:
I would prefer a client side solution if it is at all possible. If not the server side is .net based.

Comment: found great answer under:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740815/how-can-i-get-the-background-color-of-a-loaded-swf-file

Comment: Nice, though I'm not using Flash so much anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the **SetBackgroundColor** tag in the .swf binary. 
Don't know how to find it, but this link could help :
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf

Comment: Thank you, if noone comes up with a client side solution I will look into this.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely place for any type of information about a loaded SWF would be on the `contentLoaderInfo` property of the Loader. There is no property for the background color. It might be possible to grab the `content` of the Loader and see if you can extract `[SWF]` metadata from it, which can include `backgroundColor` as a property. It might not be available in all cases, though, and there's probably a good chance that the compiler doesn't actually keep this metadata by default to be accessible to ActionScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running php on your server you can use the [PHP SWF Reader](http://www.sephiroth.it/swfreader.php) to find this, and I'm sure there are similar libraries for other languages.

Comment: Thanks for the link. We are using .net though. And I am looking for a client side solution if it is posible. (I have update the question to reflect this).