# SWF has transparent background !

Tags: html, swfobject

I have an html code to embed SWF files in my page , the files when displayed have a transparent background ! i don't want that .

So i removed this `<param name="WMODE" value="transparent"> <embed wmode="transparent"` from the code and it worked !.. but i don't want that too as i need to place an invisible DIV over the flash .

any clues on how to fix the transparent background of te SWF and leave the transparent DIV on top of it ?

Thanks

Comment: It should be easy to leave the `wmode` in place, and wrap another `<div>` around the object and give that a `background-color`, shouldn't it?

Comment: hi Pekka , the problem is users may upload many SWF files with diffirent background color :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the wmode setting, and use a parent flash to load into.  Using the code here: [How can I get the background color of a loaded swf file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740815/how-can-i-get-the-background-color-of-a-loaded-swf-file) you can get the background color of the loaded swf and use it to set a colored box in your container.