# Inherit stage background from a child SWF and set the parent's to match

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a wrapper flash file that loads an external SWF based on the contents of a file entry. The wrapper has no interface of its own and only used as a middleman to load the proper child. The issue I have is the children can have varying different stage background colors and I need the parent to inherit this from the child when loaded.

```
if (ActiveSlide == null)
{
    var ActiveSlide = "";
}

if (myLoader == null)
{
    var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();  
}

var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    if (e.target.data != ActiveSlide)
    {
        var Incoming:Loader = myLoader;
        ActiveSlide = e.target.data;

        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(ActiveSlide);
        Incoming.load(url);

        addChild(Incoming);
        stage.color = Incoming.stage.color;
        myLoader.unloadAndStop();
    }
}

myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("CurrentSlide.txt?time=" + new Date().getTime()));
```

You can see the line where I have `stage.color = Incoming.stage.color;` does not work as I had hoped.

Comment: Loaded swf do not have any stage to start with. There's only one stage and it's owned by the first swf to run. You might have set different colors for the stage in your loaded swf but since they are loaded by another swf they don't have a stage anymore. Your design is simply faulty so you need to come up with another one.

Comment: @BotMaster any ideas?

Comment: yes simply set a variable in your loaded swf with the color you want then set your stage (the only one) to that color.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740815/how-can-i-get-the-background-color-of-a-loaded-swf-file

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis that's more along the lines of what I was looking for, never expected it to be so complex tho. I figured it would be as simple as referencing the files stage object even though its not initialized.

Comment: Well, the nice thing is you can take that same byte array (reset the position to 0) and load them with `loader.loadBytes`,  that way you only need one load operation.